# build fail with gcc4.6 but not with gcc4.5

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

we here use `-Werror=unused-but-set-variable` gcc compiler option while building our code. Apparently the people using gcc4.5 can build it "even though" there are variables which are set but not used afterwards. But I using gcc4.6 cannot build the code. Is that particular gcc option not implemented in gcc4.5?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The GCC 4.6 warnings are improved w.r.t. to those produced by GCC 4.5. But you could just use `-Wunused-but-set-variable` to get warnings, not errors, and more importantly correct your source code (perhaps by removing that useless variable).